# Matching strings based upon part match

Tags: php

Im pulling in data from a 6 live feeds which is sometimes have slightly different formatting, ie. i might have

- 'arsenal' and 'arsenal fc'
- 'T Walcot' and 'Theo Walcot' and 'T. Walcot'

What i was wandering was, is there a simple way to check if the strings match each other on the basis of if they have a certain % of letters in the same order they would be considered the same.

I susppose i could setup a list of related words and terms, but this would mean having to setup it up in advance, but i was wandering if there was an easier, on the fly automated way as i wont be able to compile a full list for a long time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a function just for that:

```
similar_text('Theo Walcott', 'T. Walcott', $similarity);
echo $similarity;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the soundex function http://php.net/soundex and the similar_text function to get a percentage of similarity.

Comment: thanks, but would that work with 'the-o wal-cot' and 't wal-cot' ? Surely the syllables are too different